# Where is the ISO for Test Agents for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, load-testing, tfs-2015

We have TFS2015 and I am trialling Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (no installation disk).

*I am now looking for an ISO with Microsoft Test Agents for Visual Studio 2015*.

[Documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents) for VS 2015 states that these ISOs should be available:

[image]

I can get the web installer (exe) for the Agents from here, but where can I get the ISO?

**Please note**: I need the ISO to get hold of Test Controller 2015 to run **Load Tests**, so just having the Agents is not enough.

Also, I have tried using Test Agents 2015 with Test Controller 2013, and my Agent configuration fails with a time out (whilst attempting to restart the service).

And finally, I have tried using Test Agents 2013 with TFS2015, which fails with a "Registry lookup failed" error on the "Agent Deployment" build step in our build definition (the powershell scripts used in this step assume that there is a path for an installed Test Agent 2015 in your registry). This problem is fixed by providing a path to Test Agent 2015 installer in "Test Agent Location" property of that build step.

So, **I am now trying to locate the ISO with Test Agents for Visual Studio 2015 - does anybody know where I can get it from, please?**

Comment: I could not find that ISO anywhere in the end.
The solution that I found for making Test Agents 2013 update 5 work with TFS 2015 was to install Test Agents 2015 (that takes care of the registry issue), then install Test Agents 2013 Update 5 on top of that - after that everything works as described in Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It was announced that Test Agent 2015 no longer needed a Test Controller, as the agent orchestration now is managed by the server (TFS or VSTS). You can also refer this [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/05/29/testing-in-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-workflows/).

> Q: Will the Test Agent 2015 support all the scenarios supported by
>   Test Controller and Test Agent of Visual Studio 2013?

A: We recommend you use Agents for Visual Studio 2015 in all the new automated testing scenarios. You can use the Deploy Test Agents task in a build definition to download and install the test agents on your machine. The following table shows the scenarios supported by Agents for Visual Studio 2013 and the alternatives for Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 and Team Services (TS).

[image]

For your situation, seems you are using on-premises Load Test , you need to use ***Test Controller/Test Agentes2013 Update5*** . More information, please refer [Using a Test Controller and Test Agents in a Load Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400223(v=vs.120).aspx)

As for ISO files, it seems [agent for VS2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750)
are using the `.iso` including test agents and test controls in download center. But for agent for Vs2015 are just using `.exe` in download center.

Comment: Thank you for getting back, Patrick-MSFT, but unfortunately, I've already tried the recommended alternative in TFS2015 (i.e. agents/controllers for 2013), but as I was saying in the question, I've identified an issue with the agent deployment build step. This is the reason I am looking for the ISO (with agents/controllers for 2015) which the documentation states should be available somewhere... :)

Comment: The `Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment` task should also support with test agent 2013, are you using the [update5 version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48140) instead of RTM version? Otherwise, why you can't just install it on that machine manually as a workaround?

Comment: Yes, I was initially using vs2013.5_agts_enu.iso - ironically, I am now trying to find a Test Controller for VS2015 as a work-around for the issues I was having with VS2013 components (as described in the question). 
According to this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546460.aspx, please see top of "How to install and configure a test controller" section), I should be able to get an ISO, however, having spent at least an hour on the phone to Microsoft this morning, it looks like they cannot find it either and need to investigate... I am still waiting for them to get back to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, go to the page below:

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/

at the scroll down the page you will see VS2015, after clicking download you will need to sign in,

then could choose the corresponding version you want to download:
do remember to sign in to Microsoft for downloading agents.
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202015%20Update%203